# What is handlebars-loader in webpack doing?

Tags: javascript, webpack, handlebars.js

I am new to handlebars and I wanted to know what exactly the loader for handlebars in webpack is doing, as there is nothing to read about it on the npm handlebars site... does it precompile the templates into .js files only? And if so, where does it output those precompiled .js file(s)? (I assume it is only 1 file with the different Handlebars.template.x functions in it...).

Answer (score 1):

It precompiles them, yes. The precompiled functions are not output to a separate file, but given to Webpack internally, and Webpack will bundle them for you. The [handlebars-loader documentation](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader#readme) mentions this, although briefly:

```js
var template = require("./file.handlebars");
// => returns file.handlebars content as a template function
```

Instead of having an object with different `Handlebars.template.TemplateName` functions, each template is compiled to a separate function, and you only get the function for the *one* specific template when you do `require('./the-file-name.handlebars')`.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, I just had problems referencing that precompiled .js file, do I just reference it like you did with a relative path './filename.handlebars', so is it available globally so to say in my project? and I just have to import them like that and webpack knows where they are? Or do I need some different approach?

Comment: And just to clarify: what is `'the-file-name.handlebars'`? Is this still my handlebars template file or is this really the precompiled javascript file from my template? the suffix .handlebars is puzzling me, what am I requiring there? so can I do e.g: `let template = require('./myTemplate.handlebars');` then  `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = template({some_Value})` ?

Comment: You're requiring your handlebars _source file_, you don't do any compilation manually. Each handlebars template would be in its own separate file with a `.handlebars` file extension (I think .hbs is also common, and you can configure webpack to accept either using the `test` option in your loader rules).

Comment: I did that and I required my .hbs files in some of my other .js files... but I don't understand it.. when I require the .hbs template files, they are not precompiled yet, but when webpack executes, it takes those .hbs templates and precompiles them to .js files in separate output files for each .hbs file... do I need to require or import those precompiled .js files somewhere in my .js files or how does it work? Because otherwise, what sense does it make to precompile them if I dont use those .js in any of my files? Or is webpack somehow doing this automatically behind the scenes?

Comment: Webpack does the magic behind the scenes. When you do `require('./file.hbs')`, webpack calls the handlebars-loader, which compiles the template, and then webpack gives you the precompiled template _instead of_ the template source code. The precompiled templates are not output to separate files but are bundled _instead of_ the template source code. So, you `require()` the handlebars _source file_, but you _get_ the precompiled template.